# Java: Shortening enum call in method

Tags: java

Is there a way of shortening `enum` array call in method to `{red, blue}`?

```
interface PropertiesInterface {
    enum Color {red, blue, yellow}
    public void setColor(Color[] color);
}

class Car {
    public PropertiesInterface setProperties() {
        return new Properties();
    }

    private class Properties implements PropertiesInterface {
        @Override
        public void setColor(Color[] color) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}

public class MyCar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setProperties().setColor(new PropertiesInterface.Color[] {PropertiesInterface.Color.red, PropertiesInterface.Color.blue});
        car.setProperties().setColor(new PropertiesInterface.Color[] {red, blue});
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import static com.yourcompany.PropertiesInterface.Color.*;
```

You can then reference as just `{red, blue}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. As long as your enum is inside the Properties Interface interface, you must write the phrase "Properties Interface" twice when calling the enum. Maybe you should try making the name of the interface shorter.